# js SetTimeout not working on initial browser load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am running a rails app and I have a survey modal that is supposed to appear 30 seconds after the home page loads. Generally this works fine except when i reboot the computer and access the site for the first time. When that happens it appears immediately. Once that happens and you close the modal things work fine on that page and the other pages that require the survey to appear.

Modal is in my application.html.erb file. I originally had modals and js script on each of the pages but that seemed redundant.  So I run the js and modal html from the application.html.erb for those controller and actions where it applies. Everything works fine except when computer is restarted and I first access the home page. THis is the case on local dev and on AWS production.

I placed the js code in the head and no change. I disabled turbolinks and also no change.  Last thing i did was place the code in the visitor's coffeescript file.

original js. Not quite sure what the ajax call does. <%= survey_time %> resolves to 30000.

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#survey_modal').modal('show');
    }, <%= @survey_time %>);
  });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    $("#survey_modal").modal('toggle');
  });
</script>
```

Is this a rails thing? 
using 4.2.5 and try body tag with 
     data-turbolinks="false"

Any clues appreciated...

Comment: Are you *certain* that "survey_time" is *always* 30000?  Have you tried adding a `console.log()` to double-check? The most likely thing to be happening is that it's coming out zero or undefined, so the `setTimeout()` does run but the timeout duration is essentially 0.

Comment: Have you tried loggin `@survey_time`? Maybe there is the problem.

Comment: Have you included jQuery? You're using it but don't mention it in your question.

Comment: Set a breakpoint when `$(document).ajaxSuccess` is fired. I wouldn't be surprised if you have some asynchronously loaded asset that causes this to be triggered, but is then later retrieved from the memory cache, so a request isn't made for subsequent loads of the page. Check your Network pane, too.